# Set pixel color by coordinates (x, y) in 1D byte array

Tags: c#, bmp

does anybody know what am i doing wrong. I'm trying to change pixel color by (x, y) coordinates on 1D byte array, but i cannot succeed, pixels are scattered everywhere around.

This is my file header:

```
file.Write(
    new byte[62]
    {
        0x42, 0x4d,
        0x3e, 0xf4, 0x1, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x3e, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x28, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0xe8, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0,
        0xe8, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x1, 0x0,
        0x1, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0xf4, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0xff, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0,
        0x0, 0x0, 0xff, 0x0});
```

This is my byte array:

```
int width = 1000;
int height = 128;

var t = new byte[width * height];
```

This is the method to set pixel (I'm pretty sure the calculation is wrong, I might need to include more of my map information, but I'm not sure what):

```
static void SetPixel(byte[] img, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{x} {y}");

        int index = (y * width + x);
        img[index] = 0x1; 
    }
}
```

Lastly, here's how I call the method:

```
 SetPixel(t, 1, 0, width, height);
```

I've tried many solutions I've found online, none of them helps. Tried playing around with width, height.

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret the data correctly, you are creating a bitmap file. You have set the value `Bits per Pixel` to 1; however, you are adding one byte per pixel. Therefore, you should set this value to 8 (one byte = 8 bits). However, this requires a color palette to be stored.

If you really want 1-bit colors (monochrome), then you must divide the byte size by 8 and set pixels by setting single bits inside the bytes.

The row size must be a multiple of 4 bytes. This function calculates it:

```cs
static int RowSize(int width)
{
    return (width / 8 + 3) / 4 * 4;
}
```

We create the pixel array with:

```cs
const int HeaderSize = 62;
const int width = 1000;
const int height = 128;

int rowSize = RowSize(width);

byte[] t = new byte[rowSize * height];
```

We could calculate the file size manually, but we can get the corresponding bytes like this...

```cs
int fileSize = t.Length + HeaderSize;
byte[] fs = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileSize);
```

(You could also use the modern [BinaryPrimitives Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.binary.binaryprimitives) instead of `BitConverter`.)

... and set them in the file header like this:

```cs
file.Write(
    new byte[HeaderSize] {
        0x42, 0x4d,             // Signature
        fs[0], fs[1], fs[2], fs[3], // File Size
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Reserved 1 + 2
        0x3e, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // File Offset to PixelArray (62)

        0x28, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // DIB Header Size
        0xe8, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, // Image Width
        0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Image Height
        0x01, 0x00,             // Planes
        0x01, 0x00,             // Bits per Pixel
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Compression
        0x00, 0xf4, 0x00, 0x00, // Image Size
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // X Pixels per Meter
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Y Pixels per Meter
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Colors in Color Table
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Important Color Count
        0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // Palette Color 1 (Blue)
        0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x00  // Palette Color 2 (Red)
    });
file.Write(t);
```

We set a pixel with:

```cs
static void SetPixel(byte[] img, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height) {
        int rowSize = RowSize(width);
        int byteIndex = y * rowSize + x / 8;
        int bitMask = 0b1000_0000 >> (x % 8);
        img[byteIndex] = (byte)(img[byteIndex] | bitMask);
    }
}
```

Also, you have set `Image Height` in the DIB header to 1000 = 0xe8, 0x03 instead of 128 = 0x80.

I just made tests and this seems to work so far.

See also:

- [BMP file format (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format).
- [Graphics_File_Formats_Second_Edition_1996](https://vintageapple.org/macbooks/pdf/Graphics_File_Formats_Second_Edition_1996.pdf), page 600 ff.

Answer (score 0):

The solution implementing the header as byte array is difficult to understand. It is easy to make things wrong. It is also not easy to use. Therefore, I present a second solution here, where I wrapped up everything inside a class `MonochromeBitmap`. I am using C# 12 features like primary constructors.

Usage example:

```cs
const int width = 1000;
const int height = 128;

var bitmap = new MonochromeBitmap(width, height, Color.White, Color.Black);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bitmap.SetPixel(x: i, y: i, width, height);
}
for (int i = 10; i < 110; i++) {
    bitmap.SetPixel(x: 10, y: i, width, height);
}
for (int i = 10; i < 110; i++) {
    bitmap.SetPixel(x: i, y: 10, width, height);
}
bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Tadas\Desktop\test.bmp");
```

The constructor expects the width and height of the bitmap as well as the two desired colors.

`MonochromeBitmap` implements the headers as structs. This is much more readable and easier to configure as a simple byte array. To be able to use the same notation as in [Graphics_File_Formats_Second_Edition_1996, page 600 ff](https://vintageapple.org/macbooks/pdf/Graphics_File_Formats_Second_Edition_1996.pdf), I declare a few type name aliases along with other usings:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DWORD = uint;
using LONG_ = int;
using WORD_ = ushort;
```

Implementation:

```cs
public class MonochromeBitmap(int width, int height, Color color0, Color color1)
{
    private readonly int _rowSize = RowSize(width);
    private readonly byte[] _pixels = new byte[RowSize(width) * height];

    public void SetPixel(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height) {
            int byteIndex = y * _rowSize + x / 8;
            int bitMask = 0b1000_0000 >> (x % 8);
            _pixels[byteIndex] = (byte)(_pixels[byteIndex] | bitMask);
        }
    }

    public void Save(string path)
    {
        using var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        int offset;
        unsafe {
            offset = sizeof(FileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapHeader) + 2 * sizeof(PaletteElement);
        }
        file.Write(GetBytes(new FileHeader(offset)));
        file.Write(GetBytes(new BitmapHeader(width, height, 1)));
        file.Write(GetBytes(new PaletteElement(color0)));
        file.Write(GetBytes(new PaletteElement(color1)));
        file.Write(_pixels);
    }

    // BMP Version 2 (Microsoft Windows 2.x)
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    private readonly struct FileHeader(int bitmapOffset)
    {
        readonly WORD_ FileType = 0x4d42; // "BM" in ASCII.
        readonly DWORD FileSize = 0;      // Can be 0 in uncompressed BMP files.
        readonly WORD_ Reserved1 = 0;     // Always 0.
        readonly WORD_ Reserved2 = 0;     // Always 0.
        readonly DWORD BitmapOffset = (DWORD)bitmapOffset;
    }

    // BMP Version 3 (Microsoft Windows 3.x)
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    private readonly struct BitmapHeader(int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel)
    {
        readonly DWORD Size = 40;       // Size of this header in bytes.
        readonly LONG_ Width = width;   // Image width in pixels. pos. = bottom-up, neg. = top-down,
                                        // does not include any scan-line boundary padding.
        readonly LONG_ Height = height; // Image height in pixels.
        readonly WORD_ Planes = 1;      // Number of color planes (always 1).
        readonly WORD_ BitsPerPixel = (WORD_)bitsPerPixel;

        // Fields added for Windows 3.x follow this line
        readonly DWORD Compression = 0;  // Compression methods used. 0 = uncompressed
        readonly DWORD SizeOfBitmap = 0; // Size of bitmap in bytes. Can be 0 in uncompressed BMP files.
        readonly LONG_ HorzResolution;   // Horizontal resolution in pixels per meter.
        readonly LONG_ VertResolution;   // Vertical resolution in pixels per meter.
        readonly DWORD ColorsUsed = (DWORD)(1 << bitsPerPixel); // Number of colors in the image.
        readonly DWORD ColorsImportant;  // Minimum number of important colors. 0 if all colors are important.
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    private readonly struct PaletteElement(Color color)
    {
        readonly byte Blue = color.B;
        readonly byte Green = color.G;
        readonly byte Red = color.R;
        readonly byte Reserved = 0; // Padding (always 0) 
    }

    private static int RowSize(int width)
    {
        return (width / 8 + 3) / 4 * 4;
    }

    private static unsafe byte[] GetBytes<T>(T data) where T : struct
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(T)];
        fixed (byte* ptr = bytes) {
            Unsafe.Copy(ptr, ref data);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Since I am using some `usafe` blocks, you must add `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` to a property group in your .csproj.

Answer (score 0):

The solution implementing the header as byte array is difficult to understand. It is easy to make things wrong. It is also not easy to use. Therefore, I present a second solution here, where I wrapped up everything inside a class `MonochromeBitmap`. I am using C# 12 features like primary constructors.

Usage example:

```cs
const int width = 1000;
const int height = 128;

var bitmap = new MonochromeBitmap(width, height, Color.White, Color.Black);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    bitmap.SetPixel(x: i, y: i);
}
for (int i = 10; i < 110; i++) {
    bitmap.SetPixel(x: 10, y: i);
}
for (int i = 10; i < 110; i++) {
    bitmap.SetPixel(x: i, y: 10);
}
bitmap.Save(@"C:\Users\Oli\Desktop\test.bmp");
```

The constructor expects the width and height of the bitmap as well as the two desired colors.

`MonochromeBitmap` implements the headers as structs. This is much more readable as a simple byte array. To be able to use the same notation as in [Graphics_File_Formats_Second_Edition_1996, page 600 ff](https://vintageapple.org/macbooks/pdf/Graphics_File_Formats_Second_Edition_1996.pdf), I declare a few type name aliases along with other usings:

```cs
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using DWORD = uint;
using LONG_ = int;
using WORD_ = ushort;
```

Implementation:

```cs
public class MonochromeBitmap(int width, int height, Color color0, Color color1)
{
    private readonly int _rowSize = RowSize(width);
    private readonly byte[] _pixels = new byte[RowSize(width) * height];

    public void SetPixel(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x >= 0 && x < width && y >= 0 && y < height) {
            int byteIndex = y * _rowSize + x / 8;
            int bitMask = 0b1000_0000 >> (x % 8);
            _pixels[byteIndex] = (byte)(_pixels[byteIndex] | bitMask);
        }
    }

    public void Save(string path)
    {
        using var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        int offset;
        unsafe {
            offset = sizeof(FileHeader) + sizeof(BitmapHeader) + 2 * sizeof(PaletteElement);
        }
        file.Write(GetBytes(new FileHeader(offset)));
        file.Write(GetBytes(new BitmapHeader(width, height, 1)));
        file.Write(GetBytes(new PaletteElement(color0)));
        file.Write(GetBytes(new PaletteElement(color1)));
        file.Write(_pixels);
    }

    // BMP Version 2 (Microsoft Windows 2.x)
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    private readonly struct FileHeader(int bitmapOffset)
    {
        readonly WORD_ FileType = 0x4d42; // "BM" in ASCII.
        readonly DWORD FileSize = 0;      // Can be 0 in uncompressed BMP files.
        readonly WORD_ Reserved1 = 0;     // Always 0.
        readonly WORD_ Reserved2 = 0;     // Always 0.
        readonly DWORD BitmapOffset = (DWORD)bitmapOffset;
    }

    // BMP Version 3 (Microsoft Windows 3.x)
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 2)]
    private readonly struct BitmapHeader(int width, int height, int bitsPerPixel)
    {
        readonly DWORD Size = 40;       // Size of this header in bytes.
        readonly LONG_ Width = width;   // Image width in pixels. pos. = bottom-up, neg. = top-down,
                                        // does not include any scan-line boundary padding.
        readonly LONG_ Height = height; // Image height in pixels.
        readonly WORD_ Planes = 1;      // Number of color planes (always 1).
        readonly WORD_ BitsPerPixel = (WORD_)bitsPerPixel;

        // Fields added for Windows 3.x follow this line
        readonly DWORD Compression = 0;  // Compression methods used. 0 = uncompressed
        readonly DWORD SizeOfBitmap = 0; // Size of bitmap in bytes. Can be 0 in uncompressed BMP files.
        readonly LONG_ HorzResolution;   // Horizontal resolution in pixels per meter.
        readonly LONG_ VertResolution;   // Vertical resolution in pixels per meter.
        readonly DWORD ColorsUsed = (DWORD)(1 << bitsPerPixel); // Number of colors in the image.
        readonly DWORD ColorsImportant;  // Minimum number of important colors. 0 if all colors are important.
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
    private readonly struct PaletteElement(Color color)
    {
        readonly byte Blue = color.B;
        readonly byte Green = color.G;
        readonly byte Red = color.R;
        readonly byte Reserved = 0; // Padding (always 0) 
    }

    private static int RowSize(int width)
    {
        return (width / 8 + 3) / 4 * 4;
    }

    private static unsafe byte[] GetBytes<T>(T data) where T : struct
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeof(T)];
        fixed (byte* ptr = bytes) {
            Unsafe.Copy(ptr, ref data);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

Since I am using some `usafe` blocks, you must add `<AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>` to a property group in your .csproj.